# Need the time in am pm instead of 24 hour format

Tags: c#

I've the following code that returns the time in 24 hour format. I want it in 12 hr am pm format

```
public void LogProcess()
    {
        string Reason = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");
        string UserName = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
        int hr = t.Hour;
        int m = t.Minute;
```

can u please guide me in this.

Comment: MSDN documentation: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: If you want the value (i. e. 3 instead of 15), just do `(dateHour % 12)`

Comment: @germi: Nope, that doesn't give you the normal 12-hour format, which is 1-12, not 0-11.

Comment: @germi Why? There is already a facility to fetch correct value.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah right. I never use it and only thought about midnight, in which case I normally say 0:... But you're right, of course.

Comment: ... and this is why Noda Time has [`LocalTime.ClockHourOfHalfDay`](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/html/P_NodaTime_LocalTime_ClockHourOfHalfDay.htm).

Comment: Caroline, this code doesn't *return* anything. Given the name of the method, presumably you're really getting the values in order to format them into a string... in which case you should perform a *single* string formatting operation, rather than splitting things up. More context would help us to help you more.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Can you get the [1-12] value without formatting it as `string` and then casting it back to `int`? I only know that way...

Comment: (I'd also avoid using a 12 hour format anyway, in almost all cases...)

Comment: @germi `I want it in 12 hr am pm format`, this doesn't explain to get the value in `int`.

Comment: @Bharadwaj That's why I first directed OP to the documentation where the string formatting options are explained. Getting the `int` value was an additional (though wrong) comment.

Comment: @germi Your first link is good, but your next comment is not wrong, but I guess it is not what OP want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** You can use `ToString()` function with [`custom date format strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the required part of the `DateTime` string.

**1.** You need to use small `hh` for getting the hours in `12` Hour format.
**2.** You need to use `tt` for getting the `AM` or `PM` string.

Try

```
string Hours = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh");
string AMorPM = DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");
```

For complete Time Info:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
int hours = Convert.ToInt32(dt.ToString("hh"));
int minutes = dt.Minute;
int seconds = dt.Second;
string AMorPM  = dt.ToString("tt");
```

**Solution 2:** You can perfomr the mod operation with 24 hour value with 12 to get the 12 hour value.

**Note:** You need to map result (after mod operation) to 1 if it is `0`.

```
int hours = (dt.Hour % 12 != 0) ? dt.Hour : 1;
string AMorPM  = dt.ToString("tt");
```

Comment: @Bharadwaj: yea that is valid, but OP is trying to capture the individual units into seprate variables.

Comment: Converting to a string and back is a really nasty way of getting the hours/minutes/seconds part.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Yes, but I saw `I want it in 12 hr am pm format` in OP's question.

Comment: @JonSkeet: i agree jon but for getting hours in 12 hour fomrat i could not find any better way.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi: Well I'd use `DateTime.Hour % 12` and then special-case the 0->12 mapping.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi the code which you gave is much comfortable as it reduces the length not much but yeah it works.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime has no implicit format, it is just a `DateTime` value.. But strings have. You can use [`hh` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) with [`DateTime.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get 12 hour-clock representation of your hour.

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
string hr = dt.ToString("hh");
string m =  dt.ToString("mm");
```

For more information, take a look at;

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Except you shouldn't call `DateTime.Now` twice, as the time could change between the two. For example, at about 3pm you could end up with "2" and "0" instead of either "2" and "59" or "3" and "0".

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, good point Jon. Updated. Thanks.